# Xperia Arc Social Phonebook Add Contact Problem

Tags: contacts, sony-xperia-arc

On my phone add new contact is failing by unexpected closure. The logs of that operation is;

```
10-13 08:06:57.801: INFO/CustomizationProvider(1340): No configuration file: /system/etc/customization/settings/com/sonyericsson/android/socialphonebook/custom_settings.xml
10-13 08:06:57.801: WARN/socialphonebook(12699): SettingsParser: No customization file exists.
10-13 08:06:57.801: ERROR/socialphonebook(12699): SettingsParser: key not found. key=[account-types]
10-13 08:06:57.831: DEBUG/szipinf(12699): Initializing inflate state
10-13 08:06:57.841: WARN/dalvikvm(12699): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2aac8560)
10-13 08:06:57.851: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12699): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
        java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Top level element must be ContactsSource
        at com.sonyericsson.android.socialphonebook.model.ExternalSource.inflate(ExternalSource.java:137)
        at com.sonyericsson.android.socialphonebook.model.ExternalSource.inflate(ExternalSource.java:108)
        at com.sonyericsson.android.socialphonebook.model.ContactsSource.superInflate(ContactsSource.java:119)
        at com.sonyericsson.android.socialphonebook.model.ContactsSource.ensureInflated(ContactsSource.java:111)
        at com.sonyericsson.android.socialphonebook.model.Sources.getInflatedSource(Sources.java:369)
        at com.sonyericsson.android.socialphonebook.model.Sources.getAccounts(Sources.java:268)
        at com.sonyericsson.android.socialphonebook.ui.EditContactActivity$AddContactTask.doInBackground(EditContactActivity.java:1438)
        at com.sonyericsson.android.socialphonebook.ui.EditContactActivity$AddContactTask.doInBackground(EditContactActivity.java:1422)
        at com.sonyericsson.android.socialphonebook.util.WeakAsyncTask.doInBackground(WeakAsyncTask.java:49)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
        ... 4 more
10-13 08:06:57.861: WARN/ActivityManager(242): Force finishing activity com.sonyericsson.android.socialphonebook/.ui.EditContactActivity
10-13 08:06:57.861: WARN/ActivityManager(242): Force finishing activity com.sonyericsson.android.socialphonebook/.SocialPhonebookActivity
```

Help please, I can't add contacts ( weird and funny !! )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical case where an app, in this case socialphonebook (package com.sonyericsson.android.socialphonebook), has messed up (or lost) its configuration and seems unable to recover from this.

Without root you can only try to **delete the apps data** (Settings -> Manage Applications). But be careful, since this is the phonebook app on the xeperia, you **will lose all your contact data.** Be sure to have a (cloud-based) backup.

Comment: the problem is Google+ application that I have installed "manually"